# I am trying to create a table (Order) using schema with mutable FK

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, schema, create-table

> Region (**RegionCode**, RegionName)
>
> Customer (**CustCode**, CustName, CustAdress, CustBalance, RegionCode)
>
> EmployeeType (**EmployeeType**, HourlyPayRate,)
>
> Employee (**EmployeeNo**, EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress, RegionCode,
>   EmployeeType)
>
> Product (**ProductCode**, ProductName, UnitPrice, StockOnHand)
>
> Order (**OrderNo**, CustCode, ProductCode, QtyOrdered, EmployeeNo)
>
> The primary keys are in Bold.
>
> A Region is uniquely identified by a RegionCode. Each Customer is
>   uniquely identified by a CustCode. Each Customer can order more than
>   one Product and each Product can have many Customers. **Each Order is
>   dealt with by an employee and an Employee can work with more than one
>   Order**.

I am confused as I do not understand if the statement in bold suggest that it is a composite key (OrderNo,EmployeeNo) or if the is a distraction in the question?

Here is how I would create a table from the `Order` schema

```
Create Table Order{
     OrderNo INT (11) AUTO INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     FOREIGN KEY CustCode REFERENCES Customer(CustCode)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
     ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     FOREIGN KEY ProductCode REFERENCES Product(ProductCode)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
     ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     QtyOrdered int (100),
     FOREIGN KEY EmployeeNo REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeNo)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
     ON UPDATE CASCADE
}
```

I would like to know if this is the correct way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understanding of the question is OK. Your teacher wants to you to have columns in the `Order` table that refer to tables `Customer`, `Employee` and `Product`.

However your code is flawed. You need to *declare the column*, then the foreign key. Declaring a foreign key does not automagically create a column.

Other issues:

- table declaration is enclosed with parentheses `()`, not `{}`
- `Order` is a reserved word in MySQL (and all other RDBMS); you need to enclose it with backticks (a wiser solution would be to choose another name for that table)

Consider:

```
Create Table `Order`(
    OrderNo INT (11) AUTO INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CustCode INT,
    ProductCode INT,
    QtyOrdered INT(100),
    EmployeeNo INT,
    FOREIGN KEY CustCode REFERENCES Customer(CustCode) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY ProductCode REFERENCES Product(ProductCode) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY EmployeeNo REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeNo) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Side note: a foreign key column *must* have the same datatype as the refering column; I assumed `INT` for all these columns, you might want to fix it according to your real schema.